# Conditional using get_the_ID() not working

Tags: php, get-the-id

I'm using this script to not show title on a specific page

```
<?php if (get_the_ID() != 50){ ?>
```

Now I need to add another page:

```
<?php if ((get_the_ID() != 50) || (get_the_ID() != 317)){ ?>
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Try -

```
<?php if ((get_the_ID() != 50) && (get_the_ID() != 317)){ ?>
```

It should be `AND` not `OR` for this compare.

Comment: To add some detail to Shazzad's answer: Because you're using || (OR) isntead of && (AND), the conditional you have set up is TRUE if 'get_the_ID' is not 50 and also if it's not 317. Since 50 != 317, any value at all — including 50 and 317 — will return true.